# the UI is not update After i call the logout method

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, chat

need your support I've been struggling with this for days. I'll appreciate any help

hi

I'm trying to learn IOS Development & No SQL Database
using Firebase

by creating a Chat app using Firebase real time database & swift

my problem is UI is not updated unless i rebuild The App

**sum up**

-the log out functionality will not work unless i rebuild the App again ( if i sign out i can login but i cant see the Chat Messages unless i rebuild the App)

- if i want to login (to see the Chat Messages) this is my Process

A- log out from the APP

B -login to the APP (here i need to be logged in ) i rebuild the App again

so every time i add a message i need to rebuild because so the signin method will get activates

the Login Method

```
extension FCViewController : FUIAuthDelegate
{
    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?)
    {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            
            return
        }

        login()
    }
    
}
        func login(
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        let googleAuthProvider = FUIGoogleAuth(authUI: authUI!) 
        let provider : [FUIAuthProvider] = [googleAuthProvider , FUIEmailAuth()] 
        authUI?.providers = provider

    _authHandle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener 
    {
        (auth : Auth , user : User?) in
        
        self.messages.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        self.messagesTable.reloadData()
        
        
        if let activeUser = user 
        {

            if (self.user != activeUser) 

            {
                self.user = activeUser 
        

self.signedInStatus(isSignedIn: true) 
                    let name = user!.email?.components(separatedBy: "@")[0] 
                    self.displayName = name! 
                    print("The first call",Auth.auth().currentUser as Any)
                }
                else
                {
                    // user must Sign in
                    self.signedInStatus(isSignedIn: false
                    self.loginSession()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

the library

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseEmailAuthUI
import FirebaseAuthUI
import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI
```

the signout Method

```
 @IBAction func signOut
 try Auth.auth().signOut()
```

the UI

```
func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .destructive, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(dismissAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When I tap the "signOut" button, the method gets called and gets executed. after the `try Auth.auth().signOut()` line of code gets executed, the current user is nil

```
(lldb) po Auth.auth().currentUser
nil
```

And if i login again
the Message will not Appear **unless i rebuild the App**

Comment: Instead of giving us bullet points, please edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Seeing your code in a relatively runnable snippet is by far the best way to increase the chances that someone can help.

Comment: i updated the code